# teb_local_planner test_optim_node crashing

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I was interested in analyzing the behavior of the [teb_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner) for move_base and therefore I started following the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials). I'm working with kinetic on 16.04.

To test it, I need to run:

```
~$ roslaunch teb_local_planner test_optim_node.launch
```

However when I enable the "optimization of multiple trajectories in distinctive topologies" with

```
~$ rosparam set /test_optim_node/enable_homotopy_class_planning True
```

I get strange behaviors.

Basically, after a while that I start moving the interactive markers the node crashes with this error:

```
[rviz-3] process has died [pid 1882, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rviz/rviz -d /opt/ros/kinetic/share/teb_local_planner/cfg/rviz_test_optim.rviz __name:=rviz __log:=/home/federiconardi/.ros/log/121ecffc-a234-11e9-8c71-e0d55e0d1e46/rviz-3.log].
log file: /home/federiconardi/.ros/log/121ecffc-a234-11e9-8c71-e0d55e0d1e46/rviz-3*.log
^C[test_optim_node-2] killing on exit
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

I don't really know what is causing the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328000/teb_local_planner-test_optim_node-crashing/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2019-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

this issue is not directly related to the teb_local_planner but to rviz in combination with nvidia graphics cards.
See [here](https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner/issues/131).

However, some potential workarounds exist (see link before), but I have not implemented/tested them yet.

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2